# What's the issue with this ParseExact code in PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell

I am using the following script...

```
$x = (Get-Date).ToString()
$x   #Yields 7/30/2013 12:00:10 PM
$formats = "M/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt"
$y = [datetime]::ParseExact($x, $formats, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
$y.ToString() #Yields 7/30/2013 12:00:10 PM
```

This works as Expected. However, I need to use multiple format string in $formats. The moment I change this $formats to...

```
$formats = "M/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt", "MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt"
```

...this script fails. As a matter of fact, I tried the same format twice and even that fails. If I understand the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) correctly, "The format of the string representation must match at least one of the specified formats exactly or an exception is thrown".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the script fail? Is there an error message? Is the output wrong?

Comment: It throws an exception. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: To make your script a bit shorter you can do `$formattedDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($x, $formats, $null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind... I found the solution. I was missing the explicit string cast :-(

The `$formats` assignment should be

```
$formats = [string[]]("M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt","M/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt","MM/d/yyyy h:m:s tt","MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt")
```

Blogged it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121083506/http://www.dotnetscraps.com:80/dotnetscraps/post/PowerShell-Tip-16-DateTime-ParseExact-with-multiple-formats.aspx).

Comment: That's because the working version creates a `String` array, whlist the non-working creates an `Object` array. Use `$formats.GetType()` to get the type and check the difference.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I was thinking that the ParseExact method will be able to take care of this! Surprisingly, it didn't.

Comment: Take a look at ParseExact's signature. As it expects a String array, what should it do when one passes an array of String's superclass? All the .Net classes are derived from Object, so there is little point about trying to try and convert the elements into more suitable a form. Look up the slicing problem for a fundamental OOP concept too.

Comment: I agree and that's how I ended up fixing it. I assumed that $x = "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" would create a string array, which it didn't. I am  quite new to PowerShell and I have learnt my lesson :-)

Comment: The blog link is dead/ goes nowhere useful. This is why you are supposed to put the relevant information in the answer and not link to somewhere else.